# batch file tabcmd to export pdf from tableau server

Tags: batch-file, tableau-api

I have used:

```
cd c:\program files\tableau\tableau server\9.2\extras\command line utility
tabcmd logout
tabcmd login –s "http://tableau.office.lan/"  –u admin –p password123
tabcmd export "tablename/dashboardname” —-pdf –f “c:\program files\export”
```

And I got error could not find directory "c:\program files\tableau\tableau server\9.2\extras\command line utility\c

I think maybe because I'm running a virtual window7 on mac...I can't figure out the true path yet. Anyone knows the answer of how to get to the true path? thanks!

```
tabcmd export "tablename/dashboardname" --csv -f "c:\tabcmd\test.csv"
```

this works but not all data got imported in the csv file.

But at the same time

```
tabcmd export "tablename/dashboardname" --fullpdf -f "c:\tabcmd"
```

doesn't work at all and it says could not find directory "c:\"

Comment: try `dir /s /b c:\tabcmd.*` to verify the directory.

Comment: I tried csv version it worked in tabcmd directory but still error out in pdf version. @Stephan , also do you know how I can get everthing exported to csv? the file got written into csv is funky and do not have all the data inside.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that software. But I noticed, with `csv` you give a file, but with `pdf` a folder only. (I assume `/f` stands for "filename"?)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a path has spaces, slap quotes on it. like:

```
cd "c:\program files\tableau\tableau server\9.2\extras\command line utility"
```

Better yet, throw quotes on it anyways. Safe practice.

Comment: `cd` even works without the quotes (only heaven knows why they did that...)

Comment: Oh? Hmm, maybe his error is a typo in the path then . . .

Comment: I think maybe because I'm running a virtual window7 on mac...I can't figure out the true path yet.